# Why isn't search aligned on the right side?

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

Almost all sites are placing search field in the right top corner.
What were the reasons to place it in the middle of the header?
I think it would be better to move it to the right as it was before.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I for one would like to see a swap of the user card/right hand buttons and the search bar.  It would also put the notification more in the center which is easier to see.

Comment: @NathanOliver, take a look at my other latest questions.

Comment: [Usability tests showed that searches increased by 8%](http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/Why-Stack-Overflow-Redesigned-the-Top-Navigation/?cb=1)

Comment: @rene, actually it should've been "field" :)

Comment: I also notice you're posting a lot of "my cheese moved" feature requests in a short time. Take some time to get used to the new design and then provide feedback.

Comment: @Qwertiy  oh, well, I tried .. ;)

Comment: @Stijn, I could've post a single request like: I'd like to see the buttons in following order https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUaqN.png and explain why, but I decided that multiple spot requests are better as they allow users to vote what do they want. By the way, yesterday I [asked](//meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4804/178988) such single question on the Russian SO.